# sum score in ajax not working with laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am creating a system based on an unstable source ie I monitor every time my application can access this source via ajax successfully.

I created a variable and could not understand how I can increment it each time the success is true.

Ajax

```
function scorePlus (id)
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('num'+id).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('total').value = value;
}
```

My blade

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            @foreach($infractions as $infraction)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ $infraction->title }}</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" id="num{{ $infraction->title }}" name="infractions[{{ $infraction->id }}]" value="0" >
                        <input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="scorePlus({{ $infraction->score }})" name="infractions[{{ $infraction->id }}]">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">Total:
        <span id="total">

        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's nothing done using ajax here. Can you please better explain the flow and the behavior expected ?

Comment: One thing almost like this demo. http://jsfiddle.net/zch11bjo/1/